# How to apply Interpolation or Binding for Ionic 3/Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, parse-platform, ionic3

my concept is to retrive data of my Parse Server where MongoDB is installed.

I succeed to display data in console but in the html template I cannot interpolate them.

Here is search.ts

```
import { localData } from './../../services/local';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Parse } from 'parse';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {User} from '../../models/User';

@Component({
selector: 'page-search',
templateUrl: 'search.html'
})

export class SearchPage {
currentUser = Parse.User.current();
query1 = new Parse.Query('Friends');
friendQuery = new Parse.Query('Friends');
query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
tmp: any;
users: any= [];
user: any= [];

loadUsers (){
this.tmp = this.localdata.getUsers();
}

initializeItems() {
 this.users;
}

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private localdata: localData) {
  this.query.find().then(data => {
  this.tmp = data; 
  console.log(this.tmp);
  this.localdata.setUsers(this.tmp);
  this.users = this.localdata.getUsers();
  console.log (this.users);
  console.log(this.users.username) 
   })
  }


getItems(ev: any) {
// Reset items back to all of the items
this.initializeItems();

// set val to the value of the searchbar
let val = ev.target.value;

// if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
 this.users = this.users.filter((user) => {
 return (user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
 })
 }
 }
 }
```

This is the local.ts where i save the array of Users

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class localData {

setUsers (users){
    window.localStorage.users_data = JSON.stringify(users);
}
getUsers(){
   return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.users_data || '[]');
}

}
```

and finally my html template search.html

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-searchbar
(ionInput)="getItems($event)" 
(ionCancel)="onCancel($event)"
[animated]= true>
</ion-searchbar>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-item class="item-avatar item-avatar-left item-button-right common-list" *ngFor="let user of users"></ion-item>
<div></div>


</ion-content>
```

in the html template, inside the div i want to user the user.username but it is not working.

How is it possible to display it?

Thank you a lot

Comment: what does your console display?post the format here

Comment: ParseUser {_objCount: 2, className: "_User", id: "DFDpRit4WD"}
1
:
ParseUser
className
:
"_User"
id
:
"2y5q7rIHPU"
_objCount
:
3
attributes
:
(...)
createdAt
:
(...)
updatedAt
:
(...)
__proto__
:
ParseObject
2
:
ParseUser {_objCount: 4, className: "_User", id: "py0JzZBxSN"}
3
:

Comment: paste the json rather an image

Comment: the first console displays only one column of table 'Users', the objectid,  and the second console displays all the columns of the table 'Users'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct your template as shown below on Ionic.

```
 <ion-content padding> 
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
          <ion-label>{{user.username}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: oh dear god..i have used the div outside of the ion-item..thank you a lot..i was struggling to many hours..

Comment: may you can help a little more..after i type in search it does filter the items, but after i cancel the searh the list is not returning to the original state

Comment: I cannot see `onCancel($event)` on your `code` above?

Comment: right, i just added this one onCancel(ev: any) {
    this.initializeItems();
  } and it is working very well ;) thank you a lot

Comment: is this true about observables and performance? [link](https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155795/discussion-between-giorgionasis-and-sampath).

Comment: `Josh` is the number one Ionic material provider. So we need to digest his experience.

Answer (score 1):

According to the screen shot of JSON you provided, it does not have username property, try this,

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-item class="item-avatar item-avatar-left item-button-right common-list" *ngFor="let user of users">
  <h1> {{user.className}}</h1>
</ion-item>
<div></div>
```

Comment: oh dear god..i have used the div outside of the ion-item..thank you a lot..i was struggling to many hours..